# Determine the number of the selected particle system

Tags: python, particles

When a mesh has multiple particle systems, one can be selected in the particle system tab (see image). In my case I have a mane and a tail assigned to a horse mesh. Now I would like to know the index of the selected particle system (the Mane in my case) to modify the correct one.

[image]

Comment: Python question? Not clear to me...

Comment: Right, a python question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`bpy.context.object.particle_systems.active_index`

[bpy.types.Object.particle_systems.active_index](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.ParticleSystems.html#bpy.types.ParticleSystems.active_index)